# LOAD DATA using Variable filename

Tags: stored-procedures, load-data-infile

I'm trying to write a stored procedure where I pass the path and file name that I want to read. I've tried various ways but always hit a problem, with the error message:

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected 'pathFile' (Identifier)
```

Below you can see the simplified version of the procedure I run that's causing the error. Any idea why it might throw syntax error?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test` (IN pathFile VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE pathFile INTO TABLE dataNew
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    (dat, x1, x2);

END
```

Comment: Your `LOAD DATA` appears to be the syntax for a `SQL*Loader` control file.  Wrapping a `CREATE PROCEDURE` around a `SQL*Loader` control file won't work.  Are you really trying to use `SQL*Loader` (an external application that you'd generally use if the file exists on your client machine)?  If the file exists on the database server, perhaps you want to define an external table and provide a procedure that does an `ALTER` on that external table to change the file that it's reading from.

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer: I'm using MYSQL (+ Workbench). And I'm still new to SQL.

I'm trying to load a set of data (from a csv file) into an empty table, which I then modify, and use INSERT to push it into an existing table. The datasets are ~5000 records long with ~6 columns.

I don't think ALTER meets my needs ... but I maybe misunderstanding.
The LOAD DATA works fine as a stand alone script, but appears not to work inside a stored procedure. So perhaps it's a limitation of STORED PROCs.

I would assume this is a regular need, so there must be a simple solution, that I'm not seeing.